# How to completely remove flash player from Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, uninstall, flash-player

I need to completely remove flash player from the system (Debian Jessie), I need some more privacy.

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove flashplugin-nonfree
```

I "removed" it using that command, but it is still visible in Firefox Developer and Iceweasel as *plugin*. How I can remove it? Where it is hidden?

Comment: I tried `su -c 'dpkg --remove flashplugin-installer'` but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed from package:

```
 apt-get remove $(dpkg -S `realpath /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/*flash*`|cut -d: -f1)
```

If not from package, then simply `rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/*flash*`

Comment: Thank you, I deleted `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so` and it seems to be ok.